# Character length for a sequence name

Tags: oracle

While creating an index on a table I was facing following error trace.

```
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00972: identifier is too long
00972. 00000 -  "identifier is too long"
*Cause:    An identifier with more than 30 characters was specified.
*Action:   Specify at most 30 characters.
```

I came to know that the `index name` can not be more than 30 characters. Also this rule is applicable to `table names`. But what about others like `sequences,triggers,column names` etc. I didn't find this rule on `sequence` name which is also an identifier right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle identifiers must be from 1 to 30 bytes long (with a few exceptions).

See [Oracles Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF00223) for further information